# javascript inline if variable assign value like php

Tags: javascript, php, ternary-operator

Hello in php I can do this:

```
$value = 0;
$test = $value === 0 ? 'it is zero!' : 'It is not zero.';
echo $test;
```

How can this be done in javascript in 1 line like in php without using the classic `if - else if` statement?

Comment: A ternary is just short for `if - else`, basically...

Comment: There are a number of places on the web where you can see a [big list of Javascript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It still works in javascript

```
value = 0;
var test = (value === 0 ? 'it is zero!' : 'It is not zero.');
console.log(test);
```

**Output**

```
it is zero!
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var value = 0;
var test = (value === 0) ? 'It is zero' : 'It is not zero!';
console.log(test);
```

By the way, it is called a Ternary Operator. [Many languages support them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

Answer (score 1):

Almost exactly the same.

```
var value = 0;
var test = (value === 0) ? 'it is zero!' : 'it is not zero';
console.log(test);
```

Output:

```
"it is zero!"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such major difference except that your $ becomes var.

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

I always prefer ternary for inline.I personally find it more readable.

```
var test =(value===0)?'it is zero!':'It is not zero.';
console.log("test check==="+test)
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/efLYf/

Comment: It works  on fiddle but the second var is not needed and causes an error

Answer (score 1):

Javascript also supports ternary operators.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

```
(value == 0)?alert('it is zero!'):alert('It is not zero.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do you 1 better in JS:

```
var value = 0;
console.log(value === 0 ? 'It is zero!' : 'it is not zero');
```

Or even shorter:

```
console.log('it is ' + ((value = 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
```

Bang, one line for your 3 php lines. Note that, this *will* result either in an Error being thrown (in strict mode), or an implied global variable being created, if `value` does not exist.
However, if the variable `value` already exists, all works perfectly fine, and the behaviour is as you'd expect it to be:

```
var value = 0;
console.log('it is ' + ((value = value || 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
//logs it is zero
value = 123;
console.log('it is ' + ((value = value || 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
//logs it is not zero
```

I tested this using an IIFE:

```
(function(value)
{//logs it is zero
    console.log('it is ' + ((value = value || 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
}());
    (function(value)
{//logs it is not zero
    console.log('it is ' + ((value = value || 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
}(123));
(function(value)
{//logs it is zero
    console.log('it is ' + ((value = value || 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
}(0));
```

To avoid the code from loggin `it is zero` when the value is undefined, or falsy:

```
(function(value)
{//coerce to numbner
    console.log('it is ' + (value === 0 || value === '0' ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');
}());
```

This will only log `it is zero` if `value` is either `'0'` or `0`. It won't for values like `false`, `undefined`, `null`...

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas: the second line will only give an error in console, because it contains a `var` declaration. The console eval's code in such a way that that is not allowed. try `console.log('it is ' + ((value = 0) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');` and you'll see it works just fine, just as `console.log('it is ' + ((value = 1) === 0 ? '':'not ') + 'zero!');` will log _"it is not zero"_

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas: What error, please specify... it worked just fine for me (chromium + node.js + firefox). If this produces an error, I'd like to know which, and why, so I can rectify my mistake, and perhaps learn a thing or two

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas: you're right, I didn't check properly, and the code I ran on node.js did not include the `var` keyword... I used an IIFE: `(function(value){console.log('It is ' + ( (value = 0) === 0 ? '' : 'not ') + 'zero!');}())`